# Can I replace a fan timer with one having duration options beyond one hour?

Tags: electrical, switch, fans

We have a dial that only goes up to an hour to control our fan so we are continuously getting up and turning it for another hour. Can this be replaced with a longer timer dial, like 12 hours?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to tell us something about what the current timer is and where it's installed. Of course other timers exist. The answer to your question requires more information, however.

Comment: If the timer is specific to the particular model of fan than there may be other issues. But if it is a generic "instead of a toggle switch" timer then replacing it should be fine. Model # of fan would be helpful, plus if you can (safely) open up the junction box holding the timer and post a picture of the wires in the box (both going out of the box and going into the timer) that would be very helpful.

Comment: you can install a switch and then it can run as long as you like

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standard fan (i.e. no smart switch), [Intermatic does make a 12-hour mechanical timer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Intermatic-20-Amp-12-Hour-Spring-Wound-In-Wall-Timer-White-SW12HWK/205478810) (no neutral required). If you want a programmable switch, you'll need a neutral wire in your switch box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you mean a standard spring-wound timer that doesn't require a neutral wire, **those are made in a variety of ranges**.  15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 hours, 8 hours, 12 hours, or values in that general area.  With, or without, an "always hold on" function.

Just buy a different one, they are under $20.